# Making a table view in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I've just started developing an IOS app for fetching data from Parse and show it in a table view. In my Parse database I've got only one table with only two columns "title" and "body". 
I managed to fetch the data from the table and store it in an array and show a list of the titles in the table view as you see:
[image: screen shot]

Now I want the user to be able to click on any of those titles one, two, ... and be taken to another page that shows the details which is the second column in the table "body". Also I need to make a button to go back to the list. I may need to create another table view controller and make a segue that transfer the id of the clicked element. 
I know this seems very basic but I'm new to Xcode and really struggling with it!
Does anyone have a youtube video or tutorial that explains that step by step?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, did you read the Apple docs on tableviews? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html

Comment: You can search in YouTube just as easily as anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the basic steps that you will need to do.
But you are on the right track.

1. Create your second ViewController with a class variable that will hold the id.
2. Create a segue on the storyboard editor from the first ViewController to the second.  Most important..**name your seque!**
   [named seque image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVuOQ.png)
3. In the first ViewController, handle the selection of the table view item, set a class variable ( I call it selectedId here), then call a performsegue.

```
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondSegue", sender: self)
```

4. Handle the navigation to the next ViewController as below.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "secondSegue" {
            let vc:SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            vc.id = selectedId
        }

    }
```

Here are some things that I also do.

When you create a tableviewcell, set its id to some value so that the cell knows what to pass.  its an easy way to store data.

Since you asked, here is a simple uiTableView tutorial on youtube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5IbNMAexJ4&t=36s